# Some Bibliography entry doesn't show in Latex pdf

Tags: latex, bibliography

This is a MRE of my code, including the bibliography:

bibliography.bib:

```
@misc{openflights,
title = {{Jani Patokallio , OpenFlights}},
howpublished = {\url{https://openflights.org/about}}
}

@misc{openflightsDatabases,
title = {{Jani Patokallio , ContentShare , OpenFlights Databases Documentation}},
howpublished = {\url{https://openflights.org/data.html}}
}

@misc{passengerChart,
title = {{IEA, World air passenger traffic evolution, 1980-2020, IEA, Paris https://www.iea.org/data-and-statistics/charts/world-air-passenger-traffic-evolution-1980-2020, IEA. Licence: CC BY 4.0}},
howpublished = {\url{https://www.iea.org/data-and-statistics/charts/world-air-passenger-traffic-evolution-1980-2020}}
}
```

main.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} %Windows
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} %Linux
%\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc} %Mac

\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,tableposition=top]{caption}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{color}

 \lstset{
         language=R,
         basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
         numbers=left,           
         numberstyle=\tiny,       
         numbersep=5pt,        
         tabsize=4,                 
         extendedchars=true,         
         breaklines=true,
         keywordstyle=\textbf,           
         stringstyle=\color{black}\ttfamily,
         showspaces=false,       
         showtabs=false,           
         xleftmargin=17pt,
         framexleftmargin=17pt,
         framexrightmargin=5pt,
         framexbottommargin=4pt,
         showstringspaces=false
 }
 
 \addto\captionsitalian{%
    \renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Codice}}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} 

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\usepackage{framed}

\begin{document}


\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\title{Some Thing}
\author{Some One}


\tableofcontents


\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliografia}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

And this is the output:

[image]

As you can see, the problem is that it doens't show anything in the bibliography. I've tried to change the type to @misc, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Did you run bibtex?

Comment: Unrelated, but you really shouldn't use the `utf8x` option with current versions of latex and you load `hyperref` too early. With few exceptions, it should be loaded after all the other packages.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz if saying bibtex you mean a .bib file, yes

Comment: Not just a bib file. You need to compile with `pdflatex filename -> bibtex filename -> pdflatex filename -> pdflatex filename`. You will also need to actually cite the entries in your document.

Comment: Unrelated, but it might not be the best idea to put all the information in the title field. Other fields like `author` do exist and they will make your life so much easier if you ever decide to switch bibliography styles. This way your bibliography style could also make sure that there is proper spacing around your punctuation marks ...